# Sort in Java with data from a database

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, select, jdbc

I'm doing a game in java and I want to make a screen to fit the ten highest scores. I have a database and I think it is best to fill an array with the data of the items.

This is the code of the class that connects to the database:

```
public Jugador[] buscarDiez() {

    Jugador[] diez = new Jugador[9];
    try {
        orden = conexion.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT user, score FROM player ORDER BY score LIMIT 9";
        rs = orden.executeQuery(sql);

        int i = 0;

        while (rs.next()) {
            diez[i].setUser(rs.getString("user"));
            diez[i].setScore(rs.getInt("score"));

            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

What I can be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you tell us what you get as output and what you would like to get?

Comment: Your code makes it look like you're trying to get the nine highest scores, not the ten highest scores.

Comment: @Mark actually looks like the 9 lowest scores. If he wants the highest scores he probably has to sort the score descending not ascending (default) as it currently is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new array object,

```
public Jugador[] buscarDiez() {

    Jugador[] diez = new Jugador[9];
    try {
        orden = conexion.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT user, score FROM player ORDER BY score LIMIT 9";
        rs = orden.executeQuery(sql);

        int i = 0;

        while (rs.next()) {
            diez[i] = new Jugador();// create new object instance
            diez[i].setUser(rs.getString("user"));
            diez[i].setScore(rs.getInt("score"));

            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    return diez;
}
```

Comment: @Alex2318 you have to accept the answer instead not say Thank you :)

Comment: sorry, i´m a dummy in this world

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't create an Object, fill this object and add it to your Array for example :

```
public Jugador[] buscarDiez() {

    Jugador[] listDiez = new Jugador[9];//<<---------Array
    try {
        orden = conexion.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT user, score FROM player ORDER BY score LIMIT 9";
        rs = orden.executeQuery(sql);

        int i = 0;
        Jugador dier;//<<------------Create your object
        while (rs.next()) {
            dier = new Jugador();//<<------Initialize your object
            diez.setUser(rs.getString("user"));//<<--set attributes
            diez.setScore(rs.getInt("score"));
            listDiez[i] = diez;//<<----------Add your object to your array
            i++;
        }
    }
    return listDiez;//<<------return your array
}
```

**Note**
But i recommend to use List instead, it is more helpful, why?
What if your query return less then 9, in this case you will get many null in your array, and this is not practice at all